# Rails 3 - returning JSON objects wrapped in a single object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a controller that returns JSON objects, that looks like this:

```
def getModels
  @vehicleModels = @vehicleModels.where(:vehicleMake_id => params[:vehicleMake])
  respond_with(@vehicleModels)
end
```

This works fine, and returns the following JSON:

```
[
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":1,"name":"A4","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":2,"name":"A5","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":3,"name":"A6","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":4,"name":"A8","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":5,"name":"TT","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":10,"name":"Touareg","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1}
]
```

The problem is that the JQuery dropdown I am trying to load the JSON into seems to be expecting a JSON root node. As such, loading the JSON above directly does not work. But if it has a root node, as follows, it works fine:

```
{"results":[
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":1,"name":"A4","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":2,"name":"A5","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":3,"name":"A6","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":4,"name":"A8","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":5,"name":"TT","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1},
{"created_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","id":10,"name":"Touareg","updated_at":"2011-06-22T15:49:06Z","vehicleMake_id":1}
]}
```

So the question is a simple one - how can I get rails to include a root node?

I should point out that I have attempted to do this by setting `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true` in my config, but that only added root nodes to each individual object, not one overall root node as I require.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following

```
 respond_with { :results => @vehicleModels }
```

Comment: Can we use `to_json` with options for a fine control of json output?